# Nvidia drivers install gone wrong and I am stuck at boot screen

Tags: boot, grub2, nvidia

So I'm on ubuntu 20.04 and I can't get past my boot screen. I also have lvm drive encryption setup if that is relevant at all. I used the autoinstall drivers command in hopes of installing Nvidia drivers.

What I've tried:
Accessing tty, failed
Loading into grub and using the root terminal, failed, I have this weird GUI error that when I select root it just freezes.
I have used a bootable usb and tried boot-repair and after running and rebooting I still hit the same problem.

Considering: lighting my computer on fire.

Edit:
I have tried blocking the Nvidia driver from grub and used recovery mode multiple times and failed. Recovery mode specifically experiences a gui issue Everytime I try and use it.

Comment: Have you tried to start from usb/disc media device or recovery mode ? (turn off several times until rescue menu appears). In there you can access to modify grub config and blacklist noveau or nvidia driver inside grub.conf =)

Comment: Reinstalling the OS is much more productive than lighting it on fire.  Did you recently make a hardware change? (Why weren't drivers already installed?) The best time to install Nvidia drivers is during system installation anyway.

Comment: I didn't change any hardware I just noticed my graphics card wasn't being used by my system. And recovery mode hasn't worked, I added that to my post a bit